# Pandas data frame select current columns without saving

Tags: python, pandas

I have the current query of pandas data frame:

```
dfV[(dfV.PERIODE<=10)&(dfV.NN==1)].RANK.value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"RANK","RANK":"COUNT"})
```

and result is this:

| index | RANK | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 362 | 11 |
| 1 | 5 | 11 |
| 2 | 89 | 11 |
| 3 | 361 | 11 |
| 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 5 | 411 | 10 |
| 6 | 290 | 10 |
| 7 | 1 | 10 |
| 8 | 49 | 10 |

How can I keep the results  `where Count == 10` without saving the data frame in new temp data frame like

```
temp   =  dfV[(dfV.PERIODE<=10)&(dfV.NN==1)].RANK.value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"RANK","RANK":"COUNT"})

temp[temp["COUNT"]==10]  ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query` at the end.  Try:

```
dfV[(dfV.PERIODE<=10)&(dfV.NN==1)].RANK.value_counts()\
                                  .reset_index()\
                                  .rename(columns={"index":"RANK","RANK":"COUNT"})\
                                  .query('COUNT == 10')
```